# Error using Flask and PostgresSQL - sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'RowProxy'

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I am creating a book review website following online tutorial. 
It seems like I am passing some skewed value `user_id` into `reviews` table.

The `user_id` is suppose to be a pure integer(smallint) but in the error message, it is showing as `(2,)` and I wondering if that's the main cause of this error.

What I am trying to do in this route is to show a detailed page of a book, and let a user submit a review. So I am getting the `username` from the stored session and using it to extract the `user_id` from `users` table and insert it into `review` table as a foreign key value `user_id`

**Here's my route that's related to the problem.**

```py
@app.route('/book/<string:isbn>', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def book(isbn):
    #import columns from database 
    res = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchone()
    #import api from Goodreads (stats) 
    r = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "L3FHyOR3IhCo3kctcUz3zg", "isbns": isbn})
    if r.status_code != 200:
      raise ValueError
    reviews_count=r.json()["books"][0]["reviews_count"]
    average_rating=r.json()["books"][0]["average_rating"]
    username = session.get("username")
    if request.method == "POST":
        review = request.form.get("comment")
        rating = request.form.get("rating")
        date = datetime.now()
        user_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username":username}).fetchone()
        db.execute("INSERT INTO reviews (user_id, review, rating, date) VALUES (:user_id, :review, :rating, :date)", {"date":date, "review":review, "rating":rating, "user_id":user_id})
        db.commit()
    return render_template("book.html", reviews_count = reviews_count, average_rating = average_rating, email = username)
```

**Here's the error message!**

[image]

Please see the code and kindly let me know where you think the problem is happening.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute()` always returns a tuple of column values for every row, even when you only select one column. To be more precise, it's actually a wrapper around a tuple, called a `RowProxy` (or a `ResultProxy` when it returns multiple rows), which offers you a little more functionality. I would change the variable names a little to emphasise that:

```py
result = db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username":username}).fetchone()
result.columns() # returns ('id',) - so you can create a dict of key value pairs
user_id = result[0]
```

although you can also keep it concise (note the comma)

```py
user_id, = db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username":username}).fetchone()
```

or

```py
user_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username":username}).fetchone()[0]
```

**Update**

I think the cleanest way to get to multiple columns is to do what I wrote in the inline comment, i.e. to create a dict of key value pairs.

```py
result = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchone()

# zip takes two lists and returns them as a list of tuples, combining
# the nth element of the first list and the nth element of the second list,
# so essentially it creates a list of key value pairs for you
book = {column: value for (column, value) in zip(result.columns(), result)}
book_id = book['id']
```

or in the case of multiple rows:

```py
result = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE author_id = :author_id", {"author_id": author_id}).fetchall()

books = [
    {column: value for (column, value) in zip(result.columns(), row)}
    for row in result
]
book_ids = [book['id'] for book in books]
```

Comment: What if i want to extract the `id` column of the `book` table?
`res = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchone()` do I go like `res.columns(id)` and `book_id = res[0]`?

Comment: #import columns from database 
    `res = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchone()`
    #assign book's id value to a variable
    `book_id = res[-1]`

i did it!

Comment: id column is at the last place of the tuple. are there any better and clean way of writing this you think?